# SQL bulk insert from Cisco Unified Communications Manager (CallManager) file extract

Tags: sql, insert, bulk, cisco, cucm

I'm trying to populate a SQL table with data from a CUCM file extract.

For some reason bulk insert seems not to work and gives me: (0 rows affected) and this has been bugging me all day today.

The SQL table is located here: [SQL Fiddle link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/59381/1)

The data is located here (under javascript): [Data can be copied and pasted into Notepad++](https://jsfiddle.net/f7dgdhcr/)

I opted to use JSFiddle to save the data as it's reasonably practical and I don't have to upload files that might be deemed dodgy.

The data from the JSFiddle can be saved into a file with Notepad++ and uploaded with the bulk insert command from the SQL fiddle. However it will not upload.

I am trying this on a SQL server 2012 (11.0.6251.0)

Actual code I use to try to import:

```
BULK INSERT CDR FROM 'R:\CDR_Telephony\Imports\cdr_StandAloneCluster_01_201605252003_107183' WITH 
(
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '0a',
    FIRSTROW=3
)
```

Comment: I've also tried changing ROWTERMINATOR to '\n' or '\r'

Comment: Interim solution is to load the files into a table with a single nvarchar(max) column and then split them into columns with this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7c900